# Kotlin : handle timeout connection okhttp

Tags: kotlin, timeout, okhttp

i am beginner in Kotlin . i try to build app using the OkHttp for make web requests to a rapidapi API downloading files when i click on button . i am already added setting connect Timeout , but i want to handle connect Timeout connection, when connect Timeout i want show to user a dialog to try again or cancel .

```
   private fun StartDwonload() {


    val url = editText.text.toString()


        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .build()

        val requests = Request.Builder()
            .url("xxxxxxx?igurl="+url)
            .get()
            .addHeader("x-rapidapi-host", "xxxxx")
            .addHeader("x-rapidapi-key", "xxxx")
            .build()
        client.newCall(requests).enqueue(object : Callback {
            override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {}

            override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response){

                val responseData = response.body()?.string()
                runOnUiThread{
                    try {
                        var json = JSONObject(responseData)
                        println("Request Successful!!")
                        println(json)
                        val responseObject = json.get("downloadurl").toString()

                        val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse((responseObject)))
                        request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI or DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                        request.setTitle("Download")
                        request.setDescription("Dwonloading ...")
                        request.allowScanningByMediaScanner()
                        request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED)
                        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS,"${System.currentTimeMillis()}.mp4")
                        print(DownloadManager.ACTION_DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE)
                        val manager = getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager
                        manager.enqueue((request))

                        progressDialog.dismiss()

                    } catch (e: JSONException) {
                        e.printStackTrace()
                    }
                }

            }
        })



    }
```

any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

On your OnFailure() method you can check whether your error is **SocketTimeoutException** like this

```
override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
if(e is SocketTimeoutException){
//do your work
}
}
```

Comment: i have error `Function invocation 'error(...)' expected`

Comment: I have updated my answer a little bit by changing the type of error, try now and let me know how it goes.

Comment: if i set `Throwable` i have error `Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onFailure(call: Call!, e: IOException!): Unit defined in okhttp3.Callback`

Comment: What happens when you are using AlertDialog in the onFailure() method itself.. as it is IOException

Comment: Are you getting any error or not? If it is not showing anything that means the onFailure() method is not triggered at all. Is this the case?

Comment: Yes l am not getting any error , post full code here ,  https://pl.kotl.in/XpXdID2xo

Comment: Ooh, the alert dialog you provided on OnFailure() method will triggered only when there will be a connection timeout exception.. 

This will work fine when you will get a SocketTimeoutException. and also do the same for IOException too. It should work well.

Comment: Because you are showing this only when the error is SocketTimeoutException

Comment: So its impossible to me them work in general ? l mean in case broken connection ?

Comment: You can check whether the user is connected to internet or not. If not do your work accordingly